# CGAffineTransform reverts upon pushing another controller

Tags: ios, xcode, cgaffinetransform

I have to place a vertical separator between two UIButtons. So I created a UIView with a height of 1 pixel and applied a CGAffineTransform to it. Here's the code:

```
 _verticalSeperator = [[UIView alloc]init];
    [_verticalSeperator setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [_verticalSeperator setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [bottomView addSubview:_verticalSeperator];
// 1 pixel height
    [bottomView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[_verticalSeperator(1)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_verticalSeperator)]];
// 40 pixels width
     [bottomView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[_verticalSeperator(40)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_verticalSeperator)]];
// centering the separator
    [bottomView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_verticalSeperator attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:bottomView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0]];
    [bottomView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_verticalSeperator attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:bottomView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1 constant:0]];

// applying the transform
_verticalSeperator.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
```

The problem is that when I push a new controller, the transform resets. It is no longer in its rotated state. I tried applying the transform again in `viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` so that it rotates again when I pop back to this controller but it has no effect.

How can I keep the separator in a permanent rotated state?

I apologize if this question has already been asked but I am unable to find it.

Comment: On what iOS version are you experiencing that? I experienced that kind behavior only on ios 8 so one work around is detecting the OS version..